# Bending stiffness of composite shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, composite, stiffness, bending

What is the method to compute the effective bending stiffness "EI" of a composite structure, in this case a shaft (as seen below).

The shaft is hollow with outer radius $r_{o}$, inner radius $r_{i}$, and modulus of elasticity $E_{1}$. Four rods are inserted into the shaft's thickness. They are placed at an equal angular separation. They have a radius of $r_{m}$ and are at a distance $r_{c}$ from the shaft's center. They are all made of the same material with modulus of elasticity $E_2$.

Is the effective bending stiffness simply the sum of all bending stiffnesses $\sum_{}^{}E_{i}\int{}\int{r^2dA}$?

[image]

Thanks!

Regards,
Omar

Comment: Are the rods a sliding fit, an interference fit or even ribbed ( like rebar)?

Comment: We can assume a rigid connection between both materials, i.e. no slip.

Answer (score 2):

The **bending** stiffness will be determined by the **second moment of area** ($I$). The formula you provide $\int\int r^2 da$ is for the **Polar Moment of area ($J_p$)**, and is valid for torsional problems.

Apart from little issue you are on the right track. Assuming that:

- **x** is the horizontal axis
- **y** is the vertical axis

then you are after **$I_{xx}$**.

Additionall, I'm going to number 1 the right most hole and proceed CCW to number the holes (so 2 at the top, 3 to the left, and 4 bottom).

For the polymeric structure you need to take the $I_{xx}$ of the cylinder and subtract the $I_xx$ of the reinfocrement holes. i.e.

$$I_{xx,poly} = I_{xx,cyl} - \sum_{i=1}^4 I_{xx, hole\; i}$$

where:

- $I_{xx,cyl}= \frac{\pi (r_o^4-r_i^4)}{4}$
- $I_{xx,hole\;1}=I_{xx,hole\;3}= \frac{\pi r_m^4}{4}$
- $I_{xx,hole\;2}=I_{xx,hole\;3}= \frac{\pi r_m^4}{4} + \pi r_m^2 r_c^2$

So after substitution:

$$I_{xx,poly} = \frac{\pi (r_o^4-r_i^4)}{4} - 4 \frac{\pi r_m^4}{4} - 2\pi r_m^2 r_c^2$$

Additionally, the reinforcement moment of area is:

$$I_{xx,reinf} =\sum_{i=1}^4 I_{xx, hole\; i} =4 \frac{\pi r_m^4}{4} + 2\pi r_m^2 r_c^2 $$

***Bottom line: Bending stiffness***

The bending stiffness is calculated by :

$$EI_{total} = E_1\cdot I_{xx,poly} + E_2\cdot I_{xx,reinf} $$